# EntityFramework Change Tracker и транзакции

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Как отражается `Rollback()` на изменениях, хранящихся в трекере? Выполняется ли для них `Detach()` или нужно делать это самостоятельно?

Не нашёл информации, возможно не так гуглю.

Comment: а почему `Rollback` должен как то отражаться на трекере?

Comment: @tym32167 может и не должен, но по факту имею ситуацию, когда после отката транзакции идёт запрос сущностей с аналогичным значением одной из пропертей и таких сущностей в трекере 2 (включая ту, что должна была откатиться), а в бд - 1

Comment: Rollback отменяет транзакцию в БД. На данных в контексте это никак не отражается. У сущностей остаются прежние состояния добавлено/изменено/удалено.

Comment: Представьте, что работаете с БД, не используя EF. Данные хранятся в списке. Вы в этот список добавили объекты, некоторые удалили, другие изменили. После чего сделали sql-запросы в БД insert/update/delete. По ходу дела был выполнен Rollback. В итоге данные в БД не изменились. Но и в списке они остались прежними.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov в документации это как-то отражено? Где почитать подробнее?